# How to see compact subgroup $H$ of hausdorff group $G$ with basis $U_i$ at $0$ s.t. $\cup_iU_i=U$ and $HU_i=U$, then $H=U$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, number-theory

This is related to Iwasawa's Local Class Field Theory, Chpt 3, Sec 3, Prop 3.6's statement.

Let $k'/k$ be finite unramified extension of local field $k$.($k$ has non-archimedean valuation.) Then $NU(k'/k)=U(k)$ where $NU(k'/k)$ is the norm of all units of $k'$ in $k$ and $U(k)$ is the unit group of field $k$.

The proof roughly uses $U(k')$ surjectivity to residue field of $k'$ and surjectivity of norm map and trace map between finite residue fields. Furthermore, one sees that filtration of unit group $U_i(k')$ of $k'$ gives rise to $NU(k')U_i(k)=U(k)$ where $U(k)$ is the set of all units of $k$ and $U_i(k)$ is the filtration of unit groups of $k$. Then the book concludes that $NU(k'/k)=U(k)$ by $NU(k'/k)$ compact and closed in Hausdorff space.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is there an easy way to see $NU(k'/k)=U(k)$? Roughly, this corresponds to the following setting. Let $G$ be a locally compact topological abelian group with basis at $0$ $U_i$ s.t. $U_i\supset U_j$ for $i\geq j$ and each $U_i$ is a topological subgroup. Let $U=\cup_iU_i$ and $H$ a compact subgroup of $G$ s.t. $HU_i=U$. Then $H=U$. I used the following arguments to see $NU(k'/k)=U(k)$.

1. Let $x\in NU(k'/k)U_i(k)=U(k)$. Then $x=c_iu_i$ with $c_i\in NU(k'/k),u_i\in U_i(k)$. Now consider $c_ic_j^{-1}=u_i^{-1}u_j\in U_{min(i,j)}$. Passing to large limit indicating that $u_i^{-1}u_j\to 1$ which forces $c_i=c_j$ for large $i,j$ where $NU(k'/k)$ compactness in Hausdorff space is used. Thus I have $u_i=u_j$ in large limit. This forces $u_i=1$. Thus $x\in NU(k'/k)$.
2. Consider $K=k'/NU(k'/k)$ as quotient topological space which is still complete and Hausdorff by $NU(k'/k)$ compact. Hence I conclude that $U_i=U$ in $K$ sense. However, $\{1\}=\cap U_i=U$. Thus I conclude that $U=NU(k'/k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is a topological group, $H \subset G$ is a closed subgroup and $U_i$ a basis of the identity of $G$ consisting of open subgroups, then $HU_i = G$ for all $i$ implies $H = G$.

*Proof.* Suppose $H \neq G$. Because $H$ is closed, the complement is open and there exists $g \in G$, $i$ such that $g U_i \subset G - H$. This contradicts that $g \in H U_i$, for if $g = h u_i$ then $g u_i^{-1} \in H$.